# configuracion para usar bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

tengo que subir los datos de un archivo txt a una tabla,
este archivo txt se ubica en el escritorio de mi computador,
trate de usar el bulk insert, pero me devolvió el siguiente error:

```
Mens. 4861, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 2
Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\dalfaro\Desktop\bulkinsert.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

consulta sql:

```
use Prueba
bulk insert juan
from 'C:\Users\dalfaro\Desktop\bulkinsert.txt'
with(
    fieldterminator = '|',
    rowterminator = '\n'
)
```

hay algo que configurar o algo asi?

Comment: ¿Dónde esta corriendo SQL Server? ¿En tu equipo?

Answer (score 0):

Si la ruta del archivo es correcta, la causa es que los permisos de acceso a la ruta del archivo no son suficientes para la cuenta del SO que usa SQL Server,

deberias darle permisos full control, en un principio sobre el archivo dale click en properties, Security, Edit, add, Escribe 'Everyone' dale click a CheckNames, click en OK, y sobre 'Everyone' marca Full Control,.

Si esto funciona gestiona un usuario con permisos para esto.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de tomar en cuenta que BULK INSERT se ejecuta desde el servidor de la base de datos. Por lo mismo, las rutas especificadas deben ser tomadas en cuenta desde el mismo y no desde el cliente que envía la instrucción.

También se debe tomar en cuenta que se ejecuta con los permisos de la cuenta del servicio de SQL (o de la cuenta proxy en caso de estar configurada) por lo que también esta cuenta debe tener permisos para acceder a la ubicación del archivo.